# Angular 11 function promise code after then not being called

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

I've got this function that contains some typescript.  I can't work out why the code after the promise is not being called.

```html
export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(jsonAppConfigService: JsonAppConfigService): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
    const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
    const resource = "asdfd";

    jsonAppConfigService.loadConfig()
      .toPromise()
      .then(()=>{
        protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read', 'mail.read']);
        protectedResourceMap.set(`${jsonAppConfigService.apiEndPoint}api/method1`, [resource]);
        protectedResourceMap.set(`${jsonAppConfigService.apiEndPoint}api/method2`, [resource]);
        protectedResourceMap.set(`${jsonAppConfigService.apiEndPoint}api/method3`, [resource]);
        protectedResourceMap.set(`${jsonAppConfigService.apiEndPoint}api/method4`, [resource]);
        protectedResourceMap.set(`${jsonAppConfigService.apiEndPoint}api/method5`, [resource]);
        protectedResourceMap.set(`${jsonAppConfigService.apiEndPoint}api/method6`, [resource]);


      }
    );
    
  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    protectedResourceMap
  };
}
```

It looks like execution in Chrome is going straight over this code.  I put a breakpoint on the first protectedResourceMap statement, but execution never reaches this point.

Seems basic - but can anyone point me in the right direction please?

By the way, this function is in app.module.ts file for a web app. it has been added into the NgModule section like this:

```
{
  provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
  deps: [JsonAppConfigService],
  useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory,
},
```

thanks

Comment: did you try to use  .catch(error ) and see if there is any error?

Comment: Why do you need to use `toPromise` ? Ever heard of `Observables` from rxjs that comes already with Angular?

Comment: no - i've never heard of Observables.  Can you please elaborate on how i can use those in this example?

Comment: i will try and catch the errors to see. thanks

Comment: @MoufeedJuboqji please add me an answer, because you are correct.  There is an error that i wasn't displaying. thanks

Comment: add the error message so we can help you

Comment: it's fine - the error message is clear and i have fixed the error thanks.  So your earlier comment was the correct answer. Please add an answer to this question, and i will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Moufeed Juboqji.  I needed to use try/catch and check the catch block. There was indeed an exception being thrown which i have resolved.